# Ejabberd muc_rooms and muc_registered tables are empty

Tags: ejabberd, muc

I am using ejabberd and its configured to use mysql. Everything is working fine. The user registration, rosters and roster groups are written in mysql table. The problem is, even though i use mod_muc_odbc I dont see any entries in those tables(muc_room and muc_registered). They are always empty. But the conference chat works just fine. Should i do any changes in mod_muc_room.erl file or am I doing anything wrong? I've been stuck with this thing for the past 4 days. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the rooms you are looking for are persistent ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I think so. I have configured ejabberd.cfg file to make all created rooms persistent, using default room options.

Comment: Can you check in a real room config using an XMPP client that the room is actually really persistent ?

Comment: I'm sorry. But how do I do that? I am using xabber right now, I dont find any options to check that. Is there any way i can find that from server side. If I see the "ejabberd live" output, something is being written in "muc_online_room" on the mnesia table. Does that mean the room is not persistent?

Comment: Well, I do not use Xabber. Use a client that allow that like Psi for example.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Yeah when I use psi on my linux system and set the room persistent, it appears on the muc_rooms table. But why wasn't it persistent when I set the value in   the configurations file(ejabberd.cfg) ?

Comment: Wrong syntax in your config file ? You are also likely using a very old ejabberd version 2.1 ?

Comment: I am using 2.1.11. Anyways I'll check my config file again or I'll make changes in client. Thanks Mickael. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting following in "DATABASE SETUP" section

default_db: odbc

it will store everything in mysql